# How create directory with permissions for temporary file downloads on IIS that survives visual studio publish

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, iis

This is probably a fairly trivial question

Is there a way to make a temporary directory (with appropriate permissions) so my MVC applications can generate/create temporary files for the user to download

```
var tempfolder = Server.MapPath(@"~/Temp");
var tempName = String.Format("{0}-{1}.xlsx", client.Name, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss"));
Directory.CreateDirectory(tempfolder);
```

I get an access denied error from the proceeding code (probably for good reason)

I can of course create that directory manually under IIS and give the appropriate permissions to the appPool. However the directory doesn't survive a publish from visual studio

Whats the common (best practice) approach to solve this problem

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the easiest way to achieve this is by creating a directory in the solution and adding a dummy file, publish, then change the permissions on the directory in question

This should all survive a republish